# Find a 1 dimensional submodule of the regular FG module and justify your answer.

Tags: representation-theory

Find a 1 dimensional submodule of the regular FG module and justify your answer.

At first I thought the identity, e, could be a 1 dimensional submodule of the regular FG module, but now I am not so sure since it isn't a module in its own right.

But I am unsure, is there a standard example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An $FG$ submodule will have to be a subspace, and furthermore invariant under multiplication by any $g \in G$.

If $G$ is a finite group, consider the element $\Sigma_{g \in G} g$.

Answer (score 1):

If an element $\sum c_gg$ is invariant under multiplication by every element of $G$ then what can we say about the coefficients $c_g$? How do they relate to each other?

Comment: are they multiples of the identity?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the $c_gg$ don't change under multiplication by every element of G?

Comment: Clearly the term $c_gg$ by itself is *not* $G$-invariant. Is English your first language? The conclusion here is that every coefficient is the same, so that the sum is a scalar multiple of $\sum_{g\in G}g$ (exactly the same as the other answer). That pretty much spoils the entire thing for you.

Comment: okay, I can understand that, but why do we know that? and what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{g\in G}c_gg$ is $G$-invariant. Then $$\sum_{g\in G}c_gg=h\sum_{g\in G}c_gg=\sum_{g\in G} c_g hg=\sum_{g\in G}c_{h^{-1}g}g$$ hence $c_g=c_{h^{-1}g}$ for all $g,h\in G$, hence $c_g$ is constant with respect to $g$, say the constant $c$, hence $\sum_{g\in G}c_gg=c\sum_{g\in G}g$ is a scalar multiple of $\sum_{g\in G}g$.

Comment: okay i understand that, but i am not sure how it relates to the question?

Comment: It relates to the question because it **answers** the question. We have a one-dimensional $G$-invariant subspace (in fact, not just fixed as a subspace, but fixed elementwise, which is stronger), which is exactly what the question was asking for.